How to use Gitlab CI_JOB_TOKEN in Package.json Dependencies
The following issue is currently stopping us from using the Gitlab CICD pipelines.
We have a ReactNative project (pr-service) in a self-managed Gitlab (Ver.17.6.2-ee) server with ultimate subscription. Out environment looks like following

Using yarn for package management
Gitlab runner is running on a MacStudio machine running on latest MacOS
Runner configured with a shell executor for the moment
Gitlab server only supports https and no intention to use ssh
Package.json file, under dependencies, there is a referrance to a separate repo (in the same gitlab server) as below
"react-native-square-pos": "git+https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@git.ourowncloud.io/app/react-native-square-pos.git"

When the CICD job is run we get the following error
`$ yarn install
yarn install v1.22.22
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads https://gitlab-ci-token:%24%7BCI_JOB_TOKEN%7D@git.ourowncloud.io/app/react-native-square-pos.git
Directory: /Users/mobileappbuilder/.colima/default/builds/t2_RoTZgC/0/app/mobile-applications/pronto-service
Output:
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. If a password was provided for Git authentication, the password was incorrect or you're required to use a token instead of a password. If a token was provided, it was either incorrect, expired, or improperly scoped. See https://git.ourowncloud.io/help/topics/git/troubleshooting_git.md#error-on-git-fetch-http-basic-access-denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.ourowncloud.io/app/react-native-square-pos.git/'`

We tried the following at different stages of our experiments

Adding the ReactNative project (pr-service) under Job Token Permission's allow list of react-native-square-pos project

Authorising 'All groups and projects' to access react-native-square-pos under same setting (since above didn't work)

Different variants of the dependency string
"react-native-square-pos": "git+https://gitlab-ci-token:$CI_JOB_TOKEN@git.ourowncloud.io/app/react-native-square-pos.git"
"react-native-square-pos": "git+https://${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@git.ourowncloud.io/app/react-native-square-pos.git"

Directly trying to clone the second project from the pipeline job just before the yarn install. This was a success
$ git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@git.ourowncloud.io/app/react-native-square-pos.git

Use a personal token in the dependency string in the package.json - This was a success as well
"react-native-square-pos": "git+https://<username>:<personal_access_token>@git.ourowncloud.io/app/react-native-square-pos.git"


Use the personal access token via variables - Same error
`"react-native-square-pos": "git+https://<username>:${PAT_VAR}@git.ourowncloud.io/app/react-native-square-pos.git"`



So we assume the issue is with how we specify the CI_JOB_TOKEN (Or any gitlab variable) in the Package.json dependency variable

Providing a authToken via .npmrc   - Same error
 `//git.ourowncloud.io/:_authToken=${CI_JOB_TOKEN}`



Can someone help us in figuring this out?

Formulating the question brought some clarity.
Finally was able to resolve it. The issue was that the Gitlab variable wasn't get evaluated within the package.json. It was working in the direct git clone as it was evaluated at the shell.
So the solution was to evaluate the CI_JOB_TOKEN at the shell level and injecting it into the package.json during the pipeline. The change was done in the before_script section in the pipeline's job
before_script:
- sed -i '' "s/git.ourowncloud.io/gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@git.ourowncloud.io/g" package.json

script:
- yarn install
This was ideal as it works in the development environment as well (where developers use their personal access tokens)
`sed -i '' "s/git.ourowncloud.io/gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@git.ourowncloud.io/g" package.json '
Note that all the references of the git.ourowncloud.io will be replaced by the above command. In ourcase there is only one within package.json
Also note that the sed command works slightly differently in GNU and BSD/MacOS (additional '' for BSD/MacOS)
try:
`sed -i.bak "s/git.ourowncloud.io/gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@git.ourowncloud.io/g" package.json'
